# Convert JPanelForm class to JFrameForm class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have one class which extends JPanel now I have to convert this class to JFrame so that by using the setVisible method of the object of this class I can call this Frame. How can I do this ?

Comment: *"I have one class which extends JPanel"*  Why?  It is generally better to just use an instance of a panel, though IDE based GUI builders will typically extend.  The only common situation where it is *necessary* to extend `JPanel` is when doing custom painting, though even that can be achieved in a `BufferedImage`.  Further, don't extend frame or other top level containers.  Again create & use an instance of one.

Answer (score 0):

Leave this class as it is "extends JPanel" and write a new class extends from JFrame and add you class that extends JPanel to this frame

Comment: for e.g. I have Learning class that extends JPanel. Now I create a new class LearningFrame which extends JFrame. Now how can I add that class to this class ?? Please explain !